# Solving ORA-12505 error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've been trying to solve this error for some time now and I want to ask finally here what I should do.

I had this error before and I re-installed Oracle and Oracle Developer in hopes of fixing, but it didn't.

Next steps I did was to go to Services and see if there something is not working. But everything seems to be ON.

[image: Services]

Then I went and checked the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora I tried a few different tutorials online but none of them worked.

[image: listener.ora]

[image: tnsnames.ora]

I changed the host to localhost, my machine's name, dns from a tutorial and none worked.
Also tried restarting the services but also didn't work.

[image: oracle settings]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Why did you install **three** listener services?

Comment: Well I didn't install them they came with me installing the oracle, and about the images, there is no other way showing what is my problem

Comment: The Oracle installer only installs a **single** listener, not three.